# RaspberryPi OS (Debian 10 Bullseye) hangs doing sudo apt upgrade

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian

I ran sudo apt upgrade after sudo apt update to prep for installing ufw. During the upgrade the system hung at "setting up logrotate..." so I had to ctl-c out. After logging back in and trying to install ufw it said "E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem." So, I had to run "sudo dpkg --configure -a". On running that it now hangs at  "Setting up openssh-server...". and on ctl-c to stop it and logging back in it will only let me run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' but it hangs doing that.

I can't run any other commands and it hangs on this one. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I must be insane (doing the same thing and expecting a different result) since I kept repeating the cycle but on the 5th(?) time it completed and now it's working.